# Add guest user to SDDM (16.10)

Tags: kubuntu, 16.10, users, sddm

I'm running Kubuntu 16.10 with SDDM and I would like to add a guest user.

I've tried to run a script by modifying `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup`, as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192891), but for some reason the script is not creating the user or mounting the `$HOME` directory (it does create the `$HOME` directory, which is set to `/tmp/guest`).

If I run the script after sddm is loaded (as root) it seems to work, but I would like to have the alternative to select the user by clicking the user selector/avatar.

Comment: FYI Kubuntu 16.10 has gone EOL. Remember to upgrade to 17.04.

Comment: Sure. But I would like to confirm that I can add the guest user before upgrading.